# Chinese characters PHP code had been garbled after PHP version upgrading

Tags: php, encoding

I am currently facing with garbled Chinese characters in PHP source code.
Before the PHP version upgrade from PHP 5x to PHP 7x, the site went well.
But after upgrading , Chinese characters in MySQL database and PHP source code had been garbled.
I already restored the MySQL database , but I have no idea how to restore the Chinese characters in PHP source code.

I've tried `mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'GB2312');`
But strange Chinese characters had appeared.

Here's garbled PHP code example.

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="<?=BORDERWIDTH?>" cellpadding="<?=TABLESPACE?>" width="100%"> 
<tr>
<td width="100%" class="header">��д���Ӻ��շ�����Ϣ</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%" bgcolor="<?=ALTBG2?>" class="smalltxt">
<ul>
<li><a href="faq.php?page=messages#1">��η��������ӣ�</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.php?page=messages#2">��λظ����ӣ�</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.php?page=messages#3">���ܹ�ɾ��������</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.php?page=messages#4">�����༭�Լ����������ӣ�</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.php?page=messages#5">�ҿɲ������ϴ�������</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.php?page=messages#6">ʲô�� Smilies��</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.php?page=messages#7">����������һ��ͶƱ��</a></li>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And you can check this link.   yidian.org

Comment: How would an upgrade of your php environment cause your source code to change? PHP runs the source code, it doesn't write it or manipulate it. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding though.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Fortunately, I found the solution. When I open the php code in sublime editor, Chinese characters were garbled. But when I open php code in google browser. I can see source code with  Chinese character. I don't know why this happens. I guess it is encoding problem.